# Call a Action method from a $scope function()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a multi-level repeating accordion. On page load , the data for the first accordion will be bind. When I click on each of the level-1 accordion, the unique ID should be passed to a Action method and the data for the next-level accordion should bind.
I am not able to pass this ID and call the Action method from angular js controller. Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong here.

CSHTML

```
<div id="itineraryAccordion" ng-repeat="itinerary in item.Itineraries">
<div>
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#itineraryAccordion" href="#collapseItinerary" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" ng-bind="itinerary.Name" data-ng-click="GetSchedule(itinerary.Name)"></a>
</div>
<div id="collapseItinerary" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false">
<div class="box-body">
<div class="box-group" id="scheduleAccordion" ng-repeat="schedule in scheList">
<div>
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#scheduleAccordion" href="#collapseSchedule" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" ng-bind="schedule.ScheduleName" > </a>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
myApp.controller('layoutController', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.GetSchedule = function (itineraryName, $scope, $http) {
    alert("Itinerary Id is " + itineraryName);
    $http.get("../SchedulePlan/GetSchedule?itineraryName=" + itineraryName).success(function (response) {
        $scope.scheList = response;
    })
};
```

Here , I am getting the itineraryName in the Alert(), but in the next line, $http.get() is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. you don't need to put `$scope` and `$http` service in function.

```
 myApp.controller('layoutController', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.GetSchedule = function (itineraryName) {
   alert("Itinerary Id is " + itineraryName);
    $http.get("../SchedulePlan/GetSchedule?itineraryName=" + itineraryName).success(function (response) {
    $scope.scheList = response;
  })
 };
```

Comment: I removed it. Still its not going inside $http.get()

Comment: also remove `href="#collapseItinerary" ` form tag

Comment: may be the url is invalid!

Comment: as previous comments, should remove $scope,$http from function parameters and i think you should set href=javascript:void(0) ...if error not solved maybe your problem in http request. you can check http status from network under inspect element. I wish it's will help you :)

Comment: I am having another issue in the above code. The Get Schedule is not responding according to the itinerary clicked. Its executing only the first time. If I click another accordion, the first data is populating. I think I should add something to that scope variable to retain the data. Any help